# Shorthand for a type 'nested' in a class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, syntax

Say I have the following TypeScript module:

```
namespace SomeVeryLongClassName {
  export type SomeTypeUsedLater = (a: string, b: number) => Promise<Array<boolean>>;
  export type SomeOtherTypeUsedLater = { c: SomeTypeUsedLater, d: number };
}

class SomeVeryLongClassName {

  private someThing: SomeVeryLongClassName.SomeTypeUsedLater;
  private someThingElse: SomeVeryLongClassName.SomeOtherTypeUsedLater;

  constructor(thing: SomeVeryLongClassName.SomeTypeUsedLater,
              otherThing: SomeVeryLongClassName.SomeOtherTypeUsedLater) {
    this.someThing = thing;
    this.someThingElse = otherThing;
  }

  /* ... */
}

export = SomeVeryLongClassName;
```

Is there any way to set this up so I don't have to prefix `SomeTypeUsedLater` with `SomeVeryLongClassName.` in the class definition?

Comment: I think you can just declare these types at top level and then export them from namespace. Also, have you considered using just regular `export` and `export default` statements?

Answer (score 0):

Just shorthand it with a new type if it makes any sense for you :)

```
namespace SomeVeryLongClassName {
  export type SomeTypeUsedLater = (a: string, b: number) => Promise<Array<boolean>>;
  export type SomeOtherTypeUsedLater = { c: SomeTypeUsedLater, d: number };
}

type SomeTypeUsedLater = SomeVeryLongClassName.SomeTypeUsedLater
type SomeOtherTypeUsedLater = SomeVeryLongClassName.SomeOtherTypeUsedLater

class SomeVeryLongClassName {

  private someThing: SomeTypeUsedLater;
  private someThingElse: SomeOtherTypeUsedLater;

  constructor(thing: SomeVeryLongClassName.SomeTypeUsedLater,
              otherThing: SomeVeryLongClassName.SomeOtherTypeUsedLater) {
    this.someThing = thing;
    this.someThingElse = otherThing;
  }

  /* ... */
}

export = SomeVeryLongClassName;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBlA9pAahATgTwBk1gBzAYQBsQooA5cZAbwCgkkIAPGNHAFyV54YydJAAqQiAFUoEACYEQvXEgC8SABQgAXEii8cAS1IAaJACNdwAK5hzuAJRqAfEgAKODIdkAeAII4OCB4PuZoaBQQIMDOzgDcrOxcPPyCwqgYEADyvAAWuBLCMvKKyjhqSIxI8LqiEIXSsgpKuGZyVrb25QC%20Cd3MzGkimQ3FzWUVddj4RKSU1HQMAHR1o02luIOSGZA5%20ThrJS3l6lO4hMTkVDT0kCuZewWSYxs4A-DXUDsQ0xdzn7cmAM2DAjAA3Fp6Ea5YwkWojZ7rY4JEHgyFQaGwgCiFFk8N2eSeRSRZQSiXgxH0OGs8F4PA0eVh%20J%2051mVwWgPu4kRRzKJkSbEFQsFaEJBxhpGZvzZ8xuyzqjwOPPGjkqAoEMKgSwx4glJAqjNIKMFjK1Ovqepxsgqov2Yj1xv6iQA9AAqJBLT1IV3O5j9IA)